# using aggregate function on a calculated column

Tags: sql, sqlite

Trying to use sum() on a newly created calculated column. The calc column name is not recognized in the sum function. Here's my code

```
select name, is_open,    
       CASE WHEN text like '%perfect%' or '%amazing%' or '%happy%' or '%delicious%'or '%fabulous%'or '%fantastic%'or '%kind%'   THEN 1
            WHEN text like '%hate%'or '%horrible%'or '%bad%'or '%angry%'or '%fantastic%'or '%expensive%'or '%disgusting%' THEN -1
       END sentiment_rating,    
       sum(sentiment_rating) as sum
from review as r left join
     business as b
     on b.id = r.business_id
where is_open is not Null and sentiment_rating is not Null
group by name
order by name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to select both the unaggregated column and the aggregated column.  So, just `sum()` the expression:

```
select name, is_open,    
       sum(CASE WHEN text like '%perfect%' or text like '%amazing%' or text like '%happy%' or text like '%delicious%' or text like '%fabulous%' or text like '%fantastic%' or text like '%kind%'   THEN 1
                WHEN text like '%hate%' or text like '%horrible%' or text like '%bad%' or text like '%angry%' or text like '%fantastic%'or '%expensive%' or text like '%disgusting%' THEN -1
           END) as sum_sentiment_rating 
from review as r left join
     business as b
     on b.id = r.business_id
where is_open is not Null and sentiment_rating is not Null
group by name, is_open
order by name ASC;
```

I'm not sure if you want one row per `name` or one row per `name`/`is_open`.  I assumed the latter and added `is_open` to the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Ken1995 . . . I hadn't noticed but the `case` conditions were malformed.

Answer (score 0):

All your `LIKE` conditions are syntactically wrong.
You can't have:

```
text like '%perfect%' or '%amazing%'....
```

the correct syntax is:

```
text like '%perfect%' or text like '%amazing%' ....
```

Then you must sum directly over the calculated with `CASE` column and include `is_open` in the grouping columns:

```
select name, is_open,    
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN text like '%perfect%' or text like '%amazing%' or text like '%happy%' or text like '%delicious%' or text like '%fabulous%' or text like '%fantastic%' or text like '%kind%' THEN 1
    WHEN text like '%hate%' or text like '%horrible%' or text like '%bad%' or text like '%angry%' or text like '%fantastic%' or text like '%expensive%' or text like '%disgusting%' THEN -1
  END) as sumrating
from review as r left join
     business as b
     on b.id = r.business_id
where is_open is not Null and sentiment_rating is not Null
group by name, is_open
order by name ASC
```